# Ultrasonic Flowmeter Using TDC-GP22 and Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm working on a project of Ultrasonic Flow Meter with TDC-GP22 using Arduino UNO. I used the library of [leokoppel](https://github.com/leokoppel/GP22)

In my code,the configurations of the registers are copied from the [Application Note of GP22](https://ams.com/documents/20143/36005/TDC-GP22_GP30_AN000283_1-00.pdf/b93ea868-e82a-4c8b-2c71-d8f602b2a102), from page 22 to page 25. I didn't use the temperature sensor so I jumped those steps related to that. No calibration neither. I just want to get some results of time of flight to be able to calculate the distance between two sensors for now.

My code for test:

```
#include "GP22.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

/*
 *  
 * Test setup (Arduino Uno, through 5->3.3V level shift)

 *     10 -> SS 
 *     11 -> MOSI
 *     12 -> MISO
 *     13 -> SCK
 *     2  -> INT
 *     5V -> VCC
 *     GND -> GND
 *     4 -> DS18B20 temperature sensor (optional)
 */

const bool DEBUG = 1;
const int FAST_MODE = 1;
const int PIN_INT = 2;

GP22 tdc(PIN_INT, DEBUG);

float cycleFactor_ns = 0; 

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Go !");

  tdc.init();

  tdc.writeRegister(0, 0x430BE800);
  tdc.writeRegister(1, 0x21444000);
  tdc.writeRegister(2, 0xA0138800);
  tdc.writeRegister(3, 0xD0A24800);
  tdc.writeRegister(4, 0x10004000);
  tdc.writeRegister(5, 0x40000000);
  tdc.writeRegister(6, 0xC0C06100);

  tdc.printConfigRegisters(); 

  byte a = tdc.readRegister(READ_REG_1);             

  Serial.println(a,HEX);
  Serial.println("Test communication: ");
  Serial.print(tdc.testCommunication());
 }  

void loop() {

  tdc.sendOpcode(OPCODE_INIT);
  tdc.sendOpcode(OPCODE_START_TOF_RESTART);
  tdc.waitForInterrupt(10000000);

  delay(20);

  Serial.println(tdc.readRegister(READ_RES_3),HEX);
}
```

From oscilloscope I got the right number of fire pulses(20) with right frequency(1MHz):
[Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLr6X.png) (the blue one is the signal of transmitter before amplification, green one is after amplification, yellow one is the signal of receiver)

But what I got from the code:

```
Go !

attached pinChangeISR_debug

Register 0: 0x430be800

Register 1: 0x21444000

Register 2: 0xa0138800

Register 3: 0xd0a24800

Register 4: 0x10004000

Register 5: 0x40000000

Register 6: 0xc0c06100



21

Test communication: 

\/Test took 180 us

1

69978000

69978000

69978000

69978000

69978000

69978000

69978000

...
```

21 is the first byte of register 1, and 1 is the result of testcommunication(). These two means the test of communication is successful. But the results of reading RES_3 are always the same, and the  waitForInterrupt() doesn't work(maybe the code shouldn't be written like this) -- Timeout all the time.

What I expect, of course, is the result can change each time it measures.(impossible to get exactly the same measurement of ToF all the time)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I am also interested to read result of TDC GP22.

Comment: I've been working with the GP22. I was wondering if you ever got yours to work. I know the datasheet says to generate a start and stop pulse across the start and stop pins, that is the route I went. I was wondering if you've made any progress since your last post about it?